# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.IDevice to int'

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I am working on a `xamarin.forms` app, using the [`monkey.robotics`](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/monkey.robotics) plugin. In my app, I want to display the property `IDevice` as either a string or and int.

I currently have the following line:

```
var data = new entry{ Longitude = await GetLongitude(), Latitude = await GetLatitude(), Percentage = bpm, Device = e.Device,  };
```

But it throws the `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.IDevice to int'` error message. I understand this, but don't know a way around it.

How would I do this?

Comment: Could you add the code for your async methods? And do you know where the error happens (inside what function) because it could be in the constructor of your class, or in any of those async ones. It is hard for anyone to help you without the code that is doing all the work (potential problems)

Comment: You could also try and place the await async calls as separate variables so you can check exactly which one is causing the problem. Ex: `var longitude = await GetLongitude();` and then use the vars when creating the new entry

Comment: How is `entry.Device` defined? Is it an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IDevice](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/blob/841cb15273c0a3ce1ddafdc37924080396788534/Source/Platform%20Stacks/Robotics.Mobile.Core/Bluetooth/LE/IDevice.cs) is an interface.  You can't convert it to an int or string.  Any class that implements IDevice will have properties like Name (a string) or ID (a GUID) that you could display instead.